# How to force makefile to include a library

Tags: gcc, makefile

I use the Intel_safe_string_lib, that is compiled as static (it is a "problem" of this library, it can't be compiled as shared as i would).

I made a library that uses this intel_safe_string_lib, and this library is compiled as shared.

Now i'm creating an application that usess my library, and  in the makefile i included my library and the intel one.

But at linking, the make tells me that, in my library, can't find the reference to the function of the intel lib that i use in my library (/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libutils.so: undefined reference to `strcat_s'     libutils.so is my library).

Now i tried in my application to use a function of the intel lib (the strcat_s), the make goes smooth, so i think that Make "thinks" that is better not to link the intel library if not necessary (it is necessary in the library, but not, if not for that test, in my application).

There is a way to "force" Make to use a library, even it is not directly needed?

I'm temporarly using a useless call to strcat_s in my application to make it compile, but i would have a more elegant way.

EDIT: this is my makefile

```
TARGET = data_scraper
LIBS = -lpq -llogger -lsafestring -ldaemonizer -lutils
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -o3

.PHONY: clean all default

default: $(TARGET)
all: default

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(wildcard *.c))
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h)

%.o: %.c $(HEADERS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  -c $< -o $@

.PRECIOUS: $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
       $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f $(TARGET)
```

Comment: Better would be to forget about the so-called "safe" string library, which requires almost as much effort to achieve genuine safety as the corresponding traditional standard library functions do.  These functions, or some variation of them, at least, are Microsoft inventions and are promoted by MS, but few people outside the MS ecosystem use them.

Comment: This not really about make at all.  This is a question about how to get make to communicate the proper flags to the linker.  IOW, you're not trying to get Make to include a library, you're trying to understand how to get Make to tell the linker to include a library.

Comment: John> i don't think so. Can you append a string to another with standard functions with only ONE line of code like the function included in safestringlib? No. You have, every time you need to do so, to check some things, and it clutters the code. with the function included in safestringlib, you have to use ONE line of code, and those functions are safe.

Comment: Of course you can, @MoreBeerPlease.  To the extent that `strcat_s()` does that, the standard `strcat()` function does it, too.  But if you mean you think that `strcat_s()` does not need the same attention to detail in coding that `strcat()` does then you are fooling yourself.

Comment: I red quite a large amount of article, and they tell that *_s functions are safe.If you use them withe the right parameters, of course. Could you give me an example of "error" in strcat_s?

Comment: @MoreBeerPlease, your proviso that the "safe" functions must be used with the right parameters is largely the issue.  If you pay enough attention to get that consistently right, then you're already focusing on exactly the same things that are necessary to use the conventional functions correctly.  And if you *don't* get the arguments right then you can get exactly the same kinds of misbehavior from the "safe" functions that you can from the traditional ones.  This is large among the reasons why these functions have not gotten much traction outside MS-land.

Comment: Also, "safe" in this sense generally means your program will have defined behavior in the event of certain kinds of bad input or, if you're lucky, in the face of certain programming errors, but that's a far cry from your program doing the right thing, or even an acceptable thing.

Comment: I never used the MS-land *_s function, but the function provided in intel lib are quite "defensive". they aren't "garbage in - garbage out". I "stressed" them under some bad input (except, obviously, uncorrect buffer length), but every time they don't produce garbage, but lift a err flag.

Answer (score 3):

> There is a way to "force" Make to use a library, even it is not directly needed?

`make` does not choose which libraries to link.  *You*, the makefile author, do.  It's not a question of applying force, but you do need to tell `make` what you want.

Details depend on your makefile and on the libraries you want to include in the link.

**Update:**

The presented makefile clarifies that the issue is not about getting the library included in the link, but rather about the semantics of the link command.  The order of link options on the command line is significant, especially for static objects.  They will be used to satisfy undefined symbols only of objects listed before them on the command line.  Thus, if libutils has link dependencies on libsafestring, then you probably need to reorder the value of your `LIBS` variable:

```
LIBS = -lpq -llogger -ldaemonizer -lutils -lsafestring
```

Comment: No, @CiccioPasticcio, they asked how to get `make` to automagically include a needed library in the link, or at least that's how I read it.  And the answer is "you don't", conveyed above in slightly different words.  As for more generally solving the OP's build problem, "Details depend on your makefile and on the libraries you want to include in the link," which they have not provided.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is my fault. As i told, i already included libsafestring.a and libutils.so (my library) in makefile, so it doesn't need to "imagine" what library to include. I would makefile to force to include even the library not "directly" used. I edited the main post for makefile

Comment: Possibly you have an issue with the order of the library options in your link command, @MoreBeerPlease, but we cannot presently evaluate that, or any other alternatives, because you have not included any makefile details in the question.  If you want a detailed answer, then we need a detailed question, including a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I added the makefile

Comment: "It's not a question of applying force". Hilarious!